# Call for certain SendKey when called, not send all the time

Tags: vb.net, symbols

This is the idea I am trying to accomplish.

Inside a textbox, I type in "An increase of 50%". I hit another button to display the exact text. Numbers, letters, and SOME symbols are displayed correctly. Yet, SOME symbols, such as % ^ ( and ) are not displayed. I've figured out that I had to use the SendKeys.Send("{%}") function to send that particular key and some of the other keys. Okay, no big deal. But what I'm trying to accomplish is that when I use the SendKeys.Send("{%}") function, it send the % EVERYTIME on the OUTPUT, even though I might've INPUT something different that didn't include it. Basically I want the % WHEN I CALL IT, not all the time. I hope this has helped. Also here is my code.

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        On Error Resume Next

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then 'Only Checked Items of the CheckedListbox

        If IntCount > CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1 Then 'If the index is higher then the max. index of the checkedlistbox
            IntCount = 0 ' The index will reset to 0
        End If
        SendKeys.SendWait(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(IntCount).ToString & "{ENTER}") 'Send keys to the active windows
        IntCount += 1 'Goto the next line

    Else 'All items

        If IntCount > CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then 'If the index is higher then the max. index of the checkedlistbox
            IntCount = 0 ' The index will reset to 0
        End If
        SendKeys.SendWait(CheckedListBox1.Items(IntCount).ToString & "{ENTER}") 'Send keys to the active windows
        IntCount += 1 'Goto the next line
        SendKeys.Send("{%}") 'HERE THE % SYMBOL IS DISPLAYED EVERYTIME. NOT WHAT I WANT! ONLY WHEN I CALL IT IN THE INPUT TEXTBOX!


    End If
```

Comment: You really need to reword your question, I have no idea what you are really asking

Comment: Trying to implement a code where "if my text contains %, replace % with "{%}". Not sure where to place it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `String.Replace` to replace the % sign with {%} for when you use it in `SendKeys.Send` if the text you want to send does not contain it then it will just return the string without modifications.

```
Dim sendThis as string = "blabla is at 100%"
SendKeys.Send(sendThis.Replace("%","{%}"))
```

If for some reason you can't or don't want to replace it you can check if your text contains a % and based on that condition send it or not

```
If CheckedListBox1.Items(IntCount).ToString.Contains("%") Then
    SendKeys.Send("{%}")
End If
```

This is how your code would look like using method 1

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    If IntCount > CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1 Then
        IntCount = 0
    End If
    SendKeys.SendWait(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(IntCount).ToString & "{ENTER}")
    IntCount += 1
Else
    If IntCount > CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        IntCount = 0
    End If
    'Replace % with {%}
    SendKeys.SendWait(CheckedListBox1.Items(IntCount).ToString.Replace("%", "{%}").ToString.Replace("^", "{^}").ToString.Replace("+", "{+}") & "{ENTER}")
    IntCount += 1
End If
```

Alternate method(better performance wise)

```
Dim sendText as string = CheckedListBox1.Items(IntCount).ToString
sendText = SendText.Replace("%", "{%}")
sendText = SendText.Replace("^", "{^}")
sendText = SendText.Replace("+", "{+}")
SendKeys.SendWait(sendText)
```

Comment: Hey Raphael. Thanks for the reply man. I've looked at your code and I am most certain that this is what I am looking for. The problem I am having is where to place it.

Comment: @Serendipitepic if you use the 1st method then you would only need 1 `SendKeys.Send` call (and add a {ENTER} at the end) and remove the 2 you have in there, for the 2nd method just replace `SendKeys.Send("{%}")` with those 3 lines and you'll have to restructure it a bit to send the `{ENTER} key lastly, all in all i think the 1st method would be the best.

Comment: @Serendipitepic check updated answer i've included how it would look like using method 1 with your code.

Comment: OMG dude you're the MF'n MANN! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Sorry Raphael to bother you again, but what about replacing more than one variable. Like replacing % and ^ and +?

Comment: @Serendipitepic just stack on `.ToString.Replace("", "")` as shown in updated answer.

Comment: There are better ways to do this as this might create a unnecessary amount of strings (the `ToString` and `Replace` both return a new string) though in this case the performance loss should be negligible.

Comment: I've updated the code you've posted. I've posted what I think is what you mean. This works and doesn't work. If I was to type in "An increase of 50% which is +40", I get 2 LINES, one being "An increase of 50% which is $0" and the other being "An increase of 50which is +40". But am trying to accomplish 1 LINE being "An increase of 50% which is +40"

Comment: @Serendipitepic that is odd, trying the code myself gave me the expected output in one line and not sending it twice like you mentioned, anyway i shall add another way to do this which also is a bit better performance wise.

Comment: You have answered my problem(s). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys has special meaning for certain characters, including the plus sign `+`, caret `^`, percent sign `%`, tilde `~`, parentheses `()`, and curly braces `{}`. When sending these characters, you must wrap them in braces `{}`. Additionally, you must wrap brackets `[]`, for compatibility reasons.
If the text you are sending is coded into your program, you can just wrap these characters manually.
But if the text is user-specified, or comes from some other source, you can wrap these characters like this:

```
Dim SendText as String = "This ^string^ might+need (to be) wrapped."
Dim sb as new Text.StringBuilder(SendText)
Dim i as Integer = 0
While i < sb.Length
  If "+^%~(){}[]".Contains(sb.Chars(i)) Then
    sb.Insert(i, "{"c)
    sb.Insert(i + 2, "}"c)
    i += 3
  Else
    i += 1
  End If
End While
SendKeys.Send(sb.ToString())
```

You can also send other keystrokes, including backspace and the arrow keys:

```
SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")
SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}")
```

For more information, [SendKeys on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Comment: this wont work as is, and will give you a runtime error something along the lines of `Keyword "{{" is not valid.` because you change the `SendText` string each iteration causing it to replace the open and close brackets you just added, if you assign it to a new string then it would work. otherwise a good method to handle these kind of isues

Comment: @RaphaelSmit I fixed it replacing it's own brackets a second time.